# tinymce 4 and file_browser_callback

Tags: symfony, tinymce-4

Im' trying to do a function file_browser_callback, mais it's seem's not working :

In my browser :

```
Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
```

Function call :

```
function elFinderBrowser (field_name, url, type, win) {
    tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file:"http://stores-concept:8899/app_dev.php/admin/elfinder/tinycme",
        title: "elFinder 2.0",
        width: 900,
        height: 450,
        resizable: 'yes'
    }, {
        setUrl: function (url) {
            win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And my tiny init :

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var $configs = {"language":"fr","file_browser_callback":"elFinderBrowser","plugins":"bootstrap code codemirror fullscreen preview table visualblocks link image media","toolbar1":"styleselect | bold italic | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link image media | bootstrap | code preview","menubar":false,"toolbar_items_size":"small","codemirror":"path: \"CodeMirror\"","script_url":"\/bundles\/whadmin\/js\/plugin\/tinymce\/tinymce.min.js"};
        var $textarea = jQuery('#wh_cmsbundle_page_body');
        if($textarea.is('[required]')) {
            $configs.oninit = function(editor) {
                editor.onChange.add(function(ed, l) { ed.save(); });
            };
        }
        $textarea.tinymce($configs);
    });
```

Comment: Where is this error thrown? Can you show the code that throws it?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function"

Comment: Nothing else. Only "a is not a function"

Comment: Same here, really annoying...

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. The example in the TinyMCE manual is wrong! They provide custom callback as string. From TinyMCE manual:

```
 tinyMCE.init({
    theme : ...,
    mode: ...,

    file_browser_callback : 'myFileBrowser'
  });
```

which is totally wrong, callback should be a function not a string. So the proper example would be:

```
 tinyMCE.init({
    theme : ...,
    mode: ...,

    file_browser_callback : myFileBrowser
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this and it worked.

```
file_browser_callback: function (fieldName, url, type, win) {
            alert("Test");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following method:

```
<script>

var myBrowser = function(field_name, url, type, win) {
    alert('Hello');
}

tinymce.init({
    file_browser_callback: myBrowser
)};
```